# Ruby: Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring

I'm just learning Ruby on Rails and in the process installing it on OSX El Capitan.

I've got Ruby on Rails fully installed with rbenv. I was able to set up my first application with running

```
rails new blog
```

This successfully created the application! It did give me a warning that I was using an older version of ruby, so I ran

```
rbenv install 2.2.3
rbenv local 2.2.3
rbenv global 2.2.3
```

Everything installed nicely, but now when I'm trying to create my first controller, I type this command:

```
rails g controller posts
```

I get this following warning, and the controller isn't set up:

```
 Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
```

After hunting around these forums, I found that people were able to solve their problems with running gem update --system, but I'm still getting the same warning.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set ruby 2.2.3 as default, which will solve you query.

first of all check the list of installed ruby versions in your machine by running: `rvm list`.
This will give you a list of all rubies and the default ruby which your machine is using.
After checking that, run `rvm --default use 2.2.3` this will make ruby 2.2.3 as default ruby.

[check this link for more info](https://rvm.io/rubies/default)